# How to find the widths of letterforms of a font of given style and size?

Tags: fonts, font-design, lettering, linux

I'm stymied trying to hand letter the text in a one off sign for my yard:

**NO LIFE

MATTERS

WHERE

BLACK LIVES

DON'T**



Using Libre Office Draw I centered the text (Liberation Sans, 72pt) in a window sized to the proportions of my sign.  I put a bounding rectangle over each word to find the position and size of each word which I used to set masks on the sign.
 [image: test]
While I could repeat this to locate the strokes of each letter, it gets old. Is there any way to get this from a font file? I have tried

```
ttfdump /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationSans-Bold.ttf
```

and other linux ttf/fc utilities but I cannot make sense of their outputs.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: I don't really understand what your end goal is here. Are you looking for a way to get the measurements of each letter? Can you outline/expand text in Libre Office Draw? Else try Inkscape. Once the letters are outlined they behave like ordinary vector objects and can be measured. I assume you don't have access to a printer. It would be so much easier to print and copy the letters (or just the widths) from the print.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do that in LibreOffice, but it's certainly possible do it in Inkscape which is also free and Open Source.

Using the Text tool, type a line of text. Do *Path > Object to Path*, then *Edit > Ungroup*.

This will break up the letters into individual objects. Using the Select tool, click on a letter to select it, and read off the width on the tool controls along the top.

For example

[image]

You could also remove the fill and apply a thin stroke, and maybe enable the page grid to help you transfer it to your sign

[image]